Why is object array null later in the script even after confirming its not null after initialization
The title. there are no mentions of the spriterenderers or array anywhere else in the program
SpriteRenderer[,] Renderer = new SpriteRenderer[8,8];
    void Awake()
    {
        if (D)
        {
            D = false;
            for (int x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y <= 7; y++)
                {
                    sq = Instantiate(square, globals.MovePos(x,y), Quaternion.identity);
                    Renderer[x,y] = new SpriteRenderer();
                    Renderer[x,y] = sq.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
                    print(Renderer[x,y] == null);//false every time
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
            if(stats.p != null)
            {
                stats.p.FindRange();
                for(int x = 0; x <= 7; x++)
                {
                    for(int y = 0; y <= 7; y++)
                    {
                        print(Renderer[x,y] == null); // true everytime
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

What should happen is that it prints false everytime.

When sq or any of its parent node is destroyed, the components will become null.

First thing you have to understand is that Unity had been written with C++, and all our C# code is nothing but a wrapper for native Unity C++ logic. Almost all Unity C# objects and methods are a mirror of its native C++ representation. This will help you to understand next lines.
The SpriteRenderer is inherited from UnityEngine.Object class, like almost every other class in UnityEngine namespace. And UnityEngine.Object has an override for comparison operator(==). Here it is, from decompiled code:

public class Object
{

...

    public static bool operator ==(Object x, Object y) => Object.CompareBaseObjects(x, y);

    private static bool CompareBaseObjects(Object lhs, Object rhs)
    {
      bool flag1 = (object) lhs == null;
      bool flag2 = (object) rhs == null;
      if (flag2 & flag1)
        return true;
      if (flag2)
        return !Object.IsNativeObjectAlive(lhs);
      return flag1 ? !Object.IsNativeObjectAlive(rhs) : lhs.m_InstanceID == rhs.m_InstanceID;
    }


    private static bool IsNativeObjectAlive(Object o)
    {
      if (o.GetCachedPtr() != IntPtr.Zero)
        return true;
      return !(o is MonoBehaviour) && !(o is ScriptableObject) && Object.DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist(o.GetInstanceID());
    }

    internal static extern bool DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist(int instanceID);
}

As you can see, there is a specific logic for cases, when any of parameters is null. In this case direct comparison isn't happened, but there are checks for native objects state. If native object pointer is IntPtr.Zero, that is null-pointer(0x0), or pointer is not null-pointer, but it points to the destroyed object, then the result of comparison will be true. DoesObjectWithInstanceIDExist is native function, so we can't check what logic it has under the hood, but, I think, semantic of this function is pretty clear.
So far, if native representation of your SpriteRenderer is destroyed, then comparison with null will return true. It could be caused by calling Destroy(...) method, or scene changing, or destroying of its parent, etc.
Therefore, you always have to keep in mind, that your variable IS NOT null. There is no way to change values of variables, without direct access to them, or their classes. You can use Renderer[x,y] is null or System.Object.ReferenceEquals(Renderer[x,y], null) to ensure if a value of your variable is really null. And if it is not null, you still may call its methods. Again, all Unity methods have native object state check under the hood, and throw an exception on calling in such state. BUT if you have own class, inherited from MonoBehavior and it has public method, you may call this method even if comparison yourObject == null returns true. Because destroying of underlying C++ object doesn't cause destroying of your C# object, it just makes == operator works in other way.
